# iOS custom and scrollable UITableView header and UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, header, scrollable

I want to know how to make a horizontal scrollable UITableView header and UITableViewCell like the app "JP Morgan Fund Watch."

The right part of the UITableView header and UITableViewCell can be scrolled.  Any idea how to make it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that effect with using UIScrollView as tableViewHeader and content area of custom UITableViewCell subclass but thinking it is trivial to implement would be naive. 
Check the following link for details.

http://theexciter.com/articles/touches-and-uiscrollview-inside-a-uitableview.html